# How to style css top using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to set top using java script.
I logged the top of the menu after adding top style, but it does not work.

How to style top using js??

Here is my codes

`const top = (document.getElementById(element).offsetTop);`

`top` is a number not String

```
document.getElementById('contentMenu').style.top = top.toString();
    
console.log("menu" +document.getElementById('contentMenu').style.top);   //output: menu
```

Comment: You need to add a unit to the the value you're assigning. For example `px`, `em` or `%`.

Comment: If `top` variable in your script is global, then it refers to the topmost browser window. `window.top` is a non-configurable DOM property, you should see an error on the line `const top = ...`.

Answer (score 1):

```
const top = document.getElementById(element).getBoundingClientRect().top;
document.getElementById('contentMenu').style.top = `${top}px`;
console.log(document.getElementById('contentMenu').style.top)
```